# jquery ui get id of child element of dragged element, when dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

I've read through many of the drag and drop threads on SO and i haven't found one that tells me how to get the child element id of the dragged element, when the dragged element is dropped.

For example if you have

```
<div id='drag'>
  <img id="something"/>//how do i get this id when #drag is dropped?
</div>

<div id='drop'>
</div>
```

and the js

```
$('#drag').draggable({
  containment: '#content',
  scrollSensitivity: 60,
  revert: 'invalid',
  cursor: 'move'
});

$('#drop').droppable({
  accept: '#albumImgs li',
  activeClass: 'dropContainerOpen',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var fileName = $(ui.draggable.attr('alt'));
    console.log(fileName);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ui.draggable is the dragged element you just need to do a query for the child you want:

```
$('#drop').droppable({
  accept: '#albumImgs li',
  activeClass: 'dropContainerOpen',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var fileName = $(ui.draggable.attr('alt'));
    console.log(ui.draggable.find('#something'))
    console.log(fileName);
  }
});
```

Comment: where does this ui.draggable come from? It's not a class or id or anything. Can you point me in the direction of some documentation?

Comment: Don't know if its documented very well, just something you find when you start digging in to the frameworks you are using.